# How to insert something in textarea at the location indicated by the mouse

Tags: javascript, insert, textarea, line, emoji

I created a script that inserts emojis inside a textarea. The problem is that I use innerHTML to insert the emoji and that way it only inserts at the beginning or end of the content of the textarea. I would like to be able to insert this in any location indicated by the user so that if you have already written what you want you can return to a certain part of the text and simply insert your emoji. Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it's not really pretty but I feel like this example has everthing to explain it, you can save the snippet in an html page, load it and examine the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insertion test</title>

    <style>
        .classic-button {
            width: 140px;
            height: 60px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 4px solid black;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        table {

            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            border: 4px solid black;
        }

        .fs-24-b {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .fs-32-b {
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .tBoxFill {
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
            box-sizing: border-box;       /* Opera/IE 8+ */
            font-size: 32px;
        }

        .td-button {
            padding: 20px;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
      let insertIn = (str1, str2, at) => {
        return str1.slice(0,at) + str2 + str1.slice(at);
      }

      function doGetCaretPosition (oField) {
        var iCaretPos = 0;

        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {

          // Set focus on the element
          oField.focus();

          // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
          var oSel = document.selection.createRange();

          // Move selection start to 0 position
          oSel.moveStart('character', -oField.value.length);

          // The caret position is selection length
          iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
        }

        // Firefox support
        else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == '0')
          iCaretPos = oField.selectionDirection=='backward' ? oField.selectionStart : oField.selectionEnd;

        // Return results
        return iCaretPos;
      }

      function getprintLastPost() {
        document.getElementById('printLastPost')
          .innerText = 'Last position : '
          + doGetCaretPosition(document.getElementById('TBtoFill'));
      }

      function insertInTBox(tBoxDOM, text) {
        let insStr = text;

        let oldCaretPos = doGetCaretPosition(tBoxDOM);
        let newCaretPos = oldCaretPos + insStr.length;

        tBoxDOM.value =  insertIn(tBoxDOM.value, insStr, oldCaretPos);

        tBoxDOM.selectionEnd = newCaretPos;
      }

      function insertStuff() {
        let toBox = document.getElementById("TBtoFill");
        let inBox = document.getElementById("TBtoInsert");

        insertInTBox(toBox, inBox.value);
      }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <textarea class="fs-24-b" id="TBtoFill" cols="70" rows="10">

                    </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="td-button">
                    <button class="classic-button" onclick="getprintLastPost()">
                        Get last pos
                    </button>
                    <span class="fs-32-b"> :
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </span>
                    <span id="printLastPost" class="fs-32-b">Last position : ?</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="1"  class="td-button">
                    <button class="classic-button" onclick="insertStuff()">
                        Insert
                    </button>
                    <span class="fs-32-b"> : </span>
                </td>

                <td style="width: 80%">
                    <textarea class="tBoxFill fs-32-b" id="TBtoInsert"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, you just take the utf8 or unicode value of the emoji and then you keep the function doGetCaretPosition() to use insertInTBox(). You slice the textbox string in two based on the last position of the caret which the function will tell you, then concatenate left-part->emoji->right part.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for. Solved my problem. All the best to you!!!